# Return type as SignIn

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, openiddict

return SignIn(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

This cause an error SignIn does not exist in current context

Comment: Does the class you are trying to call this in inherit from `Controller`?

Comment: Do you have specific code and error message?